# How can I use MultiDexApplication in libGDX for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, libgdx

I read many discussions about this topic but no any an exact answer I found. One says you should use Android Studio instead of Eclipse because it supports Gradle and uses Maven building. But I develop games in Eclipse using libGDX and it supports Gradle and Maven building too. Another says you should add `multidex.jar` from your path SDK tools or from Gradle then enable it inside gradle then extends `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application` then install it inside `attachBaseContext` method. Nice, but it doesn't work.

And how can I extend `MultiDexApplication` instead of `AndroidApplication`?.
Does libGDX has modification class on `Application` like `AndroidApplication` but in `MultiDexAndroidApplication` case?

Another says you shoud convert your project into Maven project or add some lines in `pom.xml` file to build many dex files!!.

I read more about this topic, but no any answer of their answers solve this problem (In libGDX using Eclipse case).

Any help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set multi dex enabled in Gradle (android/build.gradle) like so:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationId = package_name
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
      disable 'ExportedContentProvider', 'IconColors'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I believe the only lines you need to add are:

```
defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationId = <your_package_name>
    }
```

Comment: I tried this way many times before. It didn't work for me. weird! Is it work with you?

Comment: I'm not sure then we have the same goal. I was getting dex errors and I found that I needed this multi dex option enabled to solve the issue. Which worked for me.

Comment: Do you use eclipse like me !?

Comment: Your answer is not useful special when I mentioned your answer in my question. :(

Comment: I moved from eclipse to android studio a while ago. Much better gradle support. This was about the same point I changed to multidex, so maybe Android studio/intelij does something else under the hood idk.