# Enable multidex in Eclipse with libgdx app

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, android-multidex

I don't know why multidex is not working for me. I'm using Eclipse and Gradle with libgdx application. I think that I've done everything like Google said but still got an error:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID
>   not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Here is my build.gradle in android project:

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
compileSdkVersion 23

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}

defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 14 

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {    
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I've even added multidex project from "SDK\extras\android\support\multidex\library" as a library to my Android project. Here is part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"    
    package="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
android:versionCode="175"
android:versionName="5.0.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="false" 
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >

    <activity android:name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.BTActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="XXXX.XXXXXX.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And in my AndroidLauncher class I have:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdActionResolver, GSActionResolver, GameHelperListener
{
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Could anybody tell me what is wrong with this configuration? Maybe I should migrate to Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) says:

> Depending on whether you override the Application class, perform **one** of the following

So you did set this in the manifest:

`android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

And this should be enough unless you override the `Application` class somewhere.

But you also put this code in the `AndroidLauncher` class (which is an `Activity`, not the `Application` - the name is confusing, see the [LibGDX javadoc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.html))

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    Multidex.install(this);
}
```

So please remove this code and check if it solves the problem.

You should also read the [Limitations of the multidex support library](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#limitations).

Additionally, I would recommend to remove the `<uses-sdk>` tag from the manifest as you specify the `minSdkVersion` in the gradle script.

Comment: I've removed overriding of attachBaseContext method and still get an error. I also removed <uses-sdk> with no luck..

Comment: What's the Android version on your device/emulator?

Comment: You may also find [this issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3950) useful. They discuss some class needed in the main dex file, which you may need to configure.

Comment: Please also add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: It has a problem to build apk so I think that Android version of device/emulator is not important. I've read this issue but they are a step further - their app crash after succesfull build - my app is not built. I have no stacktrace because my app doesn't start..

Comment: Oh, I was thinking you are able to build the app. So it looks like the multidex is not applied at all. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011769/how-can-i-use-multidexapplication-in-libgdx-for-android#comment57912425_35012751) is someone's comment on migrating to Android Studio from Eclipse so maybe you should also give it a try.